# Can't login in ASP.NET Core 7 MVC with JWT token

Tags: c#, jwt, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-7.0

App details: ASP.NET Core 7, CQRS, JWT

I have 2 endpoints - in the API, I can login and use app features, but `IsAuthenticated` is false:

```
    [HttpPost("Login")]
    [ProducesDefaultResponseType(typeof(JwtTokenDto))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] AuthCommand command)
    {
        var result = await _mediator.Send(command);

        // if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        return Ok(result);

        // return BadRequest("failed");
    }
```

In the ASP.NET Core MVC view, `IsAuthenticated` is false as well, and I can't login. After attempting to login, the call to

```
return RedirectToAction("Index" ...)
```

and the login fails:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ProducesDefaultResponseType(typeof(JwtTokenDto))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginUserDto dto)
    {
        AuthCommand command = new(dto);

        var result = await _mediator.Send(command);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Token))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { Token = result.Token });
        }

        return BadRequest("User is not authenticated");
    }
```

My handler page

```
public async Task<JwtTokenDto> Handle(AuthCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var result = await _identityService.SigninUserAsync(request.dto);

    if (!result)
    {
        throw new BadRequestException("Invalid username or password");
    }

    var user = await _identityService.GetUserByNameAsync(request.dto.Username);

    JwtTokenDto token = await _identityService.GetJwtSecurityTokenAsync(user);

    return token;
}
```

Sign in `userAsync` method:

```
    public async Task<bool> SigninUserAsync(LoginUserDto request)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(request.Username)
            ?? throw new BadRequestException("User Doesn't exist!");

        if (user.UserName == request.Username)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(request.Username, request.Password, true, false);

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                throw new NotFoundException("user is not allowed");
            }

            await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

            return result.Succeeded;
        }

        throw new BadRequestException("User Not Found!");
}
```

GetUserByNameAsync method

```
public async Task<ApplicationUser> GetUserByNameAsync(string userName)
{
        if (userName != null)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);

            if (user != null)
                return user;

            throw new BadRequestException("User not found");
        }

        throw new BadRequestException("Can't search for null value!");
}
```

`GetJwtSecurityTokenAsync` method:

```
public async Task<JwtTokenDto> GetJwtSecurityTokenAsync(ApplicationUser user)
{
    var jwtOptions = _appSettings.JwtIssuerOptions;

    // Obtain existing claims, Here we will obtain last 4 JTI claims only
    // As We only maintain login for 5 maximum sessions, So need to remove other from that
    var allClaims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
    var toRemoveClaims = new List<Claim>();
    var allJtiClaims = allClaims.Where(claim => claim.Type.Equals(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti)).ToList();

    if (allJtiClaims.Count > 4)
    {
        toRemoveClaims = allJtiClaims.SkipLast(4).ToList();
        allJtiClaims = allJtiClaims.TakeLast(4).ToList();
    }

    var secretKey = _configuration["JwtIssuerOptions:SecretKey"];

    SigningCredentials credentials = new(new SymmetricSecurityKey(
      Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtOptions.SecretKey)), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

    DateTime tokenExpireOn = DateTime.Now.AddHours(3);

    if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")?
      .Equals("Development", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == true)
    {
        // If its development then set 3 years as token expiry for testing purpose
        tokenExpireOn = DateTime.Now.AddYears(3);
    }

    string roles = string.Join("; ", await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user));

    // Obtain roles of user
    IList<string> rolesOfUser = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

    // Add new claims
    string userName = user.UserName
           ?? throw new NotFoundException("cant find user");

    List<Claim> tokenClaims = new()
        {
            new(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")),
            new(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName),
            new(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id),
            new(ClaimTypes.Role, rolesOfUser.FirstOrDefault() ?? "Member"),
            //new Claim("user_role", "admin")
        };

    // Make JWT token
    JwtSecurityToken token = new(
          issuer: jwtOptions.Issuer,/* _config("JwtIssuerOptions:Issuer"),*/
          audience: jwtOptions.Audience, /*_config("JwtIssuerOptions:Audience"),*/
          claims: tokenClaims.Union(allJtiClaims),
          expires: tokenExpireOn,
          signingCredentials: credentials
    );

    // Set current user details for business & common library
    string userEmail = user.Email ?? throw new NotFoundException("The email value cannot be empty");

    var currentUser = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(user.Email) ?? throw new NotFoundException("No user found with this email");

    // Update claim details
    await _userManager.RemoveClaimsAsync(currentUser, toRemoveClaims);
    var claims = await _userManager.AddClaimsAsync(currentUser, tokenClaims);

    // Return it
    JwtTokenDto generatedToken = new()
                {
                    Token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                    ExpireOn = tokenExpireOn,
                    UserDetails = await GetUserDetailsAsync(currentUser)
                };

    return generatedToken;
}
```

If other things are needed, tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced your problem. In the code you provided, you returned the token as a routing parameter, which will cause the JWT token not add to the request header, so the JWT validation and authorization is fail. Generally, we need to return the JWT token to the client and store it.  It can be saved in a cookie, and the Token will also be saved in the user's browser and can be used in subsequent requests then extract the Token from the Cookie and verify it. Here is an example you can use as a reference:

In the Login method, I’m using the `_jwtHelper.CreateToken()` method to generate the JWT token：

```
public ActionResult<string> Login()
{
    var result =  _jwtHelper.CreateToken();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
    {
        Response.Cookies.Append("Token", result, new CookieOptions
        {
            HttpOnly = true, 
            Secure = true,   
            SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict, 
        });
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    return BadRequest("User is not authenticated");

}
```

I configure a handler to extract the Token from the cookie and add it to the request header:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnMessageReceived = context =>
        {
            context.Token = context.Request.Cookies["Token"];
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
    };
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true, 
        ValidIssuer = configuration["Jwt:Issuer"], 
        ValidateAudience = true, 
        ValidAudience = configuration["Jwt:Audience"], 
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true, 
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["Jwt:SecretKey"])), 
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), 
        RequireExpirationTime = true,
    };
});
```

When I did not obtain the token, accessing the home/index page failed.
[image]

When I login:
[image]

I can successfully access the index/home page:
[image]